# Get search term not on searh results page?

Tags: search

I would like to get the last term that was searched, but when not in the search.php page.
For that, I know, I could use **get_search_query()** function, but if user clicks on a post for example, so he is now in the single item and that function will retrieve an empty string.
I want to preserve that search phrase and get it on other page.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for 2 day storage or more? Or are you looking for just as long as the users is still logged in. If user logs out then wipe search history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution would be to store the search phrase on the client-side via local storage or, where not available, in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the client-side way you might use the [WordPress Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) or just regular PHP sessions as suggested here: http://old.nabble.com/The-WordPress-way-to-store-temporary-per-user-data-(sessions)--td29723244.html